# ¿Qué es "hacer la coperacha"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, definiciones, méxico

> Canadienses hacen “coperacha” para jornaleros mexicanos accidentados.

¿Qué significa esa expresión?

Comment: Fíjate en que es una deformación de la palabra "cooperación".

Comment: Micro mecenazgo, crowdfunding... [Leído en Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/4yzh8p/qu%C3%A9_es_hacer_la_coperacha/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el centro de México también se le dice "hacer la vaca": una colecta para reunir dinero.

Answer (score 4):

Según el [diccionario en línea Oxford de español](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/definicion/espanol/coperacha), "coperacha" es una expresión coloquial mexicana que significa

> Recaudación de donativos hechos con un mismo fin, especialmente si es
>   de tipo benéfico o caritativo. Sinónimo: colecta.